# Accidentals on trills and turns in MusicXML

Tags: accidentals, trills, musicxml

On trills and turns, in order to change the pitch of the note above or below, in printed music, accidentals are displayed right above or below the trill or turn. I don't see how this is expressed in MusicXML - the trill-step or or two-note-turn attributes don't seem to serve the purpose, and accidental-mark is either a notation or ornament in its own right instead of being attached to the trill-mark or turn (or delayed-turn, etc.) ornament.

Comment: Might be a bad sign that I've consistently had to both put little pictures of flats on top of "tr" trill markings in Musescore and place invisible flatted notes in measures with such trills in that program. These may be signs that MusicXML depends on similar kludges to depict trills with accidentals on top (or below, for that matter). (Musescore even disgustingly put the ottava line in between the "tr" and the little flat by default in one of my scores, forcing me to correct this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<accidental-mark>` element refers to the ornament that precedes it when used as a child of the `<ornaments>` element. See for instance the [accidental-mark example](https://www.w3.org/2021/06/musicxml40/musicxml-reference/examples/accidental-mark-element-ornament/) or the [ornaments description](https://www.w3.org/2021/06/musicxml40/musicxml-reference/elements/ornaments/). The attributes that you mention represent playback, and are not widely supported in current applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, totally makes sense; what confused me was that neither Finale NotePad (2012) nor Sibelius (2021.2 build 3268) are apparently able to handle those.